# Why aren't all file templates that are available in the Add New Item dialog available in the New File dialog?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio, if I have a solution open and choose File > New, the New File dialog provides me with a number of templates. However, if I, say, have an ASP.NET MVC project open, right click it and choose Add > New Item, the Add New Item shows *way* more item templates. For instance, I can add a new JSON file to my project this way, but I can't just create a new JSON file via File > New, because the template isn't available there.

I often want to just create a one-off JSON file to see some proper formatting and coloring, and basically mess around with it, but then discard it without saving it. With Add New Item, it creates a new file and checks my project out from source control, which is too much hassle to correct if you just want to see some JSON code with proper formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain! It looks like the only way to achieve the desired behavior is to save a new file with `.json` extension so VS can figure out the proper editor.